# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am getting this error at runtime.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)' on a
>   null object reference

**StackTrace:**

```
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437): Process: home.saket, PID: 1437
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{home.saket/home.saket.addmember.Add_Update_User}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):     at home.saket.addmember.Add_Update_User.onCreate(Add_Update_User.java:38)
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
01-12 03:44:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):     ... 10 more
01-12 03:44:54.272: W/ActivityManager(472):   Force finishing activity home.saket/.addmember.Add_Update_User
01-12 03:44:54.273: E/ActivityManager(472): Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 384x384
```

Below I am posted the codes and pointed out the error line.

**Add_Update_User.java:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_update_screen);

    // set screen
    Set_Add_Update_Screen();

    // set visibility of view as per calling activity
    String called_from = getIntent().getStringExtra("called");

    if (called_from.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {  --->38th error line
        add_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        update_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {

        update_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        add_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        USER_ID = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_ID"));

        Contact c = dbHandler.Get_Contact(USER_ID);  

        add_name.setText(c.getName());
        add_mobile.setText(c.getPhoneNumber());
        add_email.setText(c.getEmail());
        // dbHandler.close();
    }
    }
```

Comment: can you try this for me plz? if("add".equalsIgnoreCase(called_from)){

Comment: @KickButtowski I tried yours.works fine.can you post your answer and explain it?

Comment: I cannot post my answer since your post has been marked as duplicate. :(

Comment: Everybody told me to suggest for null check.your answer was solved me.But now you can't post your answer because it is closed.sorry for that. @KickButtowski

Comment: it was a good question anyway. I am sure what I suggested is right but I cannot remember the reason. hope you found that

Comment: I didn't have skype.I am accepted Elliott Frisch.this is the only answer I am looking for other than yours. @KickButtowski

Comment: @KickButtowski I am not worried for marked this as duplicate.But I couldn't accept your answer.

Comment: it is totally fine as long as you are happy. thank you so much :)

Comment: take a look at my answer in this post for more info if you like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392935/checking-if-a-jtextfield-contains-correct-string/27392947#27392947

Comment: ok .sure @KickButtowski

Comment: you may wanna see this discussion as well http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68625/madandi

Comment: @ Kick Buttowski thankyou for this answer! Its work fine!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`called_from` must be `null`. Add a test against that condition like

```
if (called_from != null && called_from.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
```

or you could use [Yoda conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) (per the **Advantages** in the linked Wikipedia article *it can also solve some types of unsafe `null` behavior* they can be described as *placing the constant portion of the expression on the left side of the conditional statement*)

```
if ("add".equalsIgnoreCase(called_from)) { // <-- safe if called_from is null
```

Comment: I love Yoda conditions...+1 for that idea!

Comment: can you explain the Yoda Conditions here plz?

Comment: @KickButtowski Edited to include some explanation.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I still do not understand how it throws NPE. how ?

Comment: @Kick The Yoda conditions don't throw NPE, that is the point of using them. What are you asking?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch if we forget about youda condition, why it throws npe when we do not use youda condition?

Comment: Because `called_from` is `null`; it must be. OP indicated the line in source, and it was `if (called_from.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {  --->38th error line` if you say `null.equalsIgnoreCase("add")` you get a NPE.

Comment: Saved my day! I can't believe this simple thing will spare me a sleep..

Answer (score 8):

This is the error line:

```
if (called_from.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {  --->38th error line
```

This means that `called_from` is null. Simple check if it is null before using it:

```
String called_from = getIntent().getStringExtra("called");

if (called_from != null && called_from.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
    // do whatever
} else {
    // do whatever
}
```

That way, if `called_from` is null, it'll execute the `else` part of your conditional.

Answer (score 4):

The exception occurs due to this statement,

```
called_from.equalsIgnoreCase("add")
```

It seem that the previous statement

```
String called_from = getIntent().getStringExtra("called");
```

returned a null reference.

You can check whether the intent to start this activity contains such a key "called".