# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

Project is working well on `emulator x86 api 6.0`.  but not on device `htc m 6.0`
here is code

```
if (img_uri != null && img_uri.equalsIgnoreCase("image")) {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.gghh);
    img_input_d.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895108/nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-boolean-java-lang-string

Comment: Add the stack trace, this can't come from img_uri being null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am answering my que I am surfing with it
so i found that some device want full specification of condition

here is my code

```
if (img_uri!=null&&!img_uri.isEmpty()&&!img_uri.equals("null")&&img_uri.equals("image") {}
```

it works for me

Answer (score 1):

You should not have a nullpointer exception since you make a null check. But anyways, you can do it like following just to be on the safe side:

```
if ("image".equalsIgnoreCase(img_uri)) {
    //...
}
```