# How to resolve Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)?

Tags: android

I have an app in which i am getting error "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)" please explain meaning and solution for that

code:-

```
 String receivedResult = parseJsonResultSetFav(result);
            if (receivedResult.equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS")) {
                CustomerTicketDialogClass ctdc = new CustomerTicketDialogClass(getActivity(),
                        "successful", "successfully sent mail to your email id ", "ViewDetails");
                ctdc.show();
                ctdc.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            } else {
                CustomerTicketDialogClass ctdc = new CustomerTicketDialogClass(getActivity(),
                        "failure", receivedResult, "ViewDetails");
                ctdc.show();
                ctdc.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            }
```

Comment: you are getting `NullPointerException` .`receivedResult` is null

Comment: not always ....

Comment: `if (receivedResult!=null && receivedResult.equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS"))`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are getting NullPointerException, so to in order to avoid this..

```
if(receivedResut != null && receivedResult.equalsIngnoreCase("SUCCESS"))
```

Comment: can you explain littel why this was happened

Comment: you can check it from here..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895108/nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-boolean-java-lang-string

Comment: have you tried to log first the value of receivedResult? Then if it is null.. check why it is happening. I guess you can check it in your parseJsonResultSetFav method because it is the one returning the result for receivedResult